# Visual basic continuing variables

Tags: variables, visual-studio-2013, calc

I am making a calculator app as my first self assigned project using Visual basic, and I want it to continue accepting numbers to calculate possibly up to a hundred different numbers, and I don't want to have to make a variable for all of them(not to even mention if that would work). The way I see it is that every different number entered into the calculator between operators would be stored as a different variable. Is this possible? maybe a work around? maybe even a better way to do it! any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a While loop you can do this fine.

All you need to do is set variables for Multiply, Subtract, Divide, and Add which should be as Booleans and declare FinalAnswer and Input as Dec.

Do something like:

```
While VariableToShowIfACalculateButtonIsPressedOrNot = False
     If Multiply = True Then
          FinalAnswer = FinalAnswer * Input
     ElseIf Divide = True Then
          FinalAnswer = FinalAnswer / Input
     ElseIf Add = True Then
          FinalAnswer = FinalAnswer + Input
     ElseIf Subtract = True Then
          FinalAnswer = FinalAnswer - Input
     End If
Loop
```

For whenever you input another number. Have this assigned to a separate button called 'AddNumber' or something.

As soon as you want to output the total of all of these then you can have another button called 'Calculate' or something which could have something like:

```
FinalAnswer = TextBoxAnswer.txt
```

You could also have this set at the bottom of the While loop which would give you a running total of all the numbers you have input so far.

Hope this makes sense!